# checking_password returns false even typing correct password

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i am checking password of user to give user info.but when i give correct password it throws password not correct error.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    # username = None
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',max_length=50,unique=True)

    phone =  models.CharField(max_length=17,blank=True)
    

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone',
        'username',
    ]

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password,make_password

## My Login View
class LoginView(APIView):
    
    serializer_class = CustomTokenCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    

    def post(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
        # Cheking email Exists
        if User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email']).exists():
            user = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])

            ## check password matches
            if check_password(request.POST['password'],user.password):
                ## Creating TOken
                token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

                serializer = UserCreateSerializerCustom(user)
                return Response({'status':True,
                                "message":"Login SuccessFull",
                                "user_info":serializer.data,
                                'token':token.key})
            else:
                return Response({'status':False,
                                "message":"Passord is not correct,Check Passsword again"})
        else:
            return Response({'status':False,
                                "message":"User Doesn't Exist,Check Email again"}
                                )
```

this is login api for my project.i'm using check_password function for checking the password,i can't find a solution for this problem.

I can login with admin username and password without any error .but can't login with user data. I think the problem is password of user is not hashing in the correct way ,How will i do this...??

**Edit**
**Registration VIew**

```
#### User registration View
class UserRegistrationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializerCustom
    # queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self,request,format=None):
        serializer = UserCreateSerializerCustom(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"Status":True,"message":"User Registered Successfully",
                    "User_info":serializer.data},
                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializer.py**

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer

class UserCreateSerializerCustom(UserCreateSerializer):
    
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'email',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phone',         
        )
```

Comment: how do you create your User objects ?

Comment: i have added it now,can you check. i can login with admin credentials but cant login with user credentials.

Comment: are you sure user is created ! why password not exists in your serializer fields ? what is set as password for your users ?

Comment: The problem was not adding password in fields of serializers.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not adding password in Fields

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer

class UserCreateSerializerCustom(UserCreateSerializer):

    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):

        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'email',
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'password',
            'phone',         
        )
```